# social media module login not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

i am trying to login with my facebook but i am getting following error.How can i solve this

```
URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.
```

Comment: How are you doing this? Could you provide some code to show the context, usually, you would use an API, for related work to facebook

Comment: @baileyhaldwin : i am working with some other developers code,maybe using HybridAuth

Comment: It seems like you are trying to log in through a script, and facebooks security detection has blocked your request.

Comment: @baileyhaldwin : then what is solution of this ? how can i solve this ?

Comment: I posted an answer, please upvote, and accept, if you found it helpful :)

Comment: Which domain name you have used when you created app in facebook ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#strict_mode

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going accessing the webpage, you use the facebook API instead, they have an open API, where you get an API Key, so Facebook can verify, your application, and not block your request.

https://developers.facebook.com/

depending on your use case, they have several open endpoints, that you can access to get different data, about users, applications etc. For security measures, it is always considered the best practice to use an open API to fetch data, from a specific website.

Comment: i already used facebook api , i created account and put my api credentials but not working